# Expose a range of ports in docker service

Tags: docker-swarm, vsftpd, docker-swarm-mode

Is there any way to expose a range of ports in the creation of a swarm service ( for instance: `-p 1024-2000:1024-2000`)? I know that it's possible for a container, but is it also possible for a Swarm Service? If yes, I can't find how to do that in the documentation.

I need this functionality for exposing a service that contains vsftpd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30560, I had the response that this functionality was available in the version **1.13**.

For the others that can't upgrade to this version, I have written a script bash that will do a loop to bind all the ports:

```sh
  expose_range(){
          p="";
          for i in `seq $1 $2`;
          do
            if [[ $3 != '--publish-rm' ]]; then
              p="$p $3 $i:$i"
            else
              p="$p $3 $i"
            fi
          done
          echo $p
  }
  command="docker service create --name vsftpd -p 2021:21 `expose_range ${vsftpd_port_min} ${vsftpd_port_max} '-p'` panubo/vsftpd"
  eval $command
```